# How to create a embed framework so I can use it in the app extension and project

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, ios8-today-widget

I am trying to create a today widget in my app. I don't want to repeat the code in the today widget project. I have been reading the pages about how to create today extension in raywenderlich and shinobicontrols. When it comes to the embed framework part, they just skip it. They didn't provide a link or tutorial on how to create a embed framework. I have googled "app extension embed framework" or "custom framework" and so on. I just couldn't find any tutorials about it? Finally I am trying here at stack overflow. Hope someone could give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the embedded frame works in app extension programming guide here
[Using an Embedded Framework to Share Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1).
And for more details watch the WWDC video [Building Modern Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#416).

Comment: I have read the guide. But it didn't mention how to create a embedded framework.

Comment: Creating framework is easy as File->New->Target under Frameworks & Library  select Cocoa touch framework

Comment: Done. So how to import file from pods in this framework?